# What's the difference between naming a function (as opposed to leaving it anon) and creating a reference to it?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, anonymous-function

In a comment on another thread I started, someone said this:

> @adlwalrus yes. try this: var foo = function bar(){}; console.log(foo); But be aware that bar is only function name (**what does it mean I'm not sure exactly myself**) and not a reference to it, so **you can't call it by doing bar()**. And assigning (even named function) is not the same as declaring a function. Hoisting (bumping to top of the scope) only works for declarations, assignment will stay in place. – valentinas 6 hours ago

What purpose does a function name serve if you can't call it with `bar()`?

Comment: What's the difference between your name and your address?

Comment: In addition to the name/address analogy, you can actually call bar() within the scope of bar(), but out of the scope of bar(), you have to use foo().

Comment: @HotLicks - That analogy makes no sense. `foo` and `bar` are both clearly *names* here. They both refer to the same *address*. It's just that one is only available within the scope of the new function.

Comment: @Iwburk that answers the question for me, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to create a function in JavaScript, a "function declaration" and a "function expression." I believe it was Doug Crockford who explained it best when he pointed out that unless "function" is the very first set of characters on a given line, you're performing a function expression (not a declaration).

Function declarations are finicky creatures. You'll recognize them when you see them. They look like this:

```
function foo() { /* ... */ }
```

They're always given a name (it's requited) and the name is locally scoped to the lexical context under which the function is declared. So if you perform a function declaration in the global context, then the function can be referenced via it's name globally. If you do it within a function, the function's name can be referenced only within that function and any functions declared within that function.

I think the most important aspect of this method of declaring a function (one that is rarely commented on) is that the function initialization gets hoisted to the top of the current lexical context. Therefore, you should never, *ever* use a function declaration within a conditional, such as this:

```
//DON'T DO THIS!
if (x) {
    function foo() { return 1; }
} else {
    function foo() { return 2; }
}

foo(); //will always be 2, regardless of the value of x.
```

A function expression is slightly different. Often, they're directly assigned to a variable, like so:

```
var foo = function() { /* ... */ };
```

This is nearly identical to the function declaration above except that the initialization is not hoisted. So you can do the following:

```
var foo;
if (x) {
    foo = function() { return 1; };
} else {
    foo = function() { return 2; };
}

foo(); //will be 1 or 2, depending on the truthy-ness of x.
```

So, back to the original question. Function expressions can also have a name, though it's not required and it's not scoped to the context in which the function is declared (as with function declarations). Instead, it gets scoped to the function's own lexical context. This is very useful in some cases. My personal favorite is this pattern:

```
(function foo() {
    //Do something.

    setTimeout(foo, 1000);
}());

foo; //undefined
```

Because of the parenthesis before the word "function", this is a function expression and the name is scoped internally only. But that's okay, because we only need to call it internally (via `setTimeout()`). The result is that the function will execute once immediately, then will re-execute every second or so after it's finishes execution. This is safer than using `setInterval()` because it will wait until it's done executing before rescheduling itself, preventing overlaps that could cause missed executions and/or "domination" of the JavaScript thread.

Essentially, the use of a named function expression is limited, but when you need it, it's very powerful.

Comment: This was an incredibly informative answer. It's been accepted, and I thought there was a way to "gift" reputation, which I would do if there is, but I can't find it.  I wish you could be my JS teacher.  If you wrote a textbook, I'd buy it. Do you have a  blog or anything?

Comment: @adlwalrus I appreciate the praise. I don't have a blog or a book or anything like that. But I do recommend you check out Doug Crockford's JavaScript lectures (do a search for "Crockford on JavaScript"). They're fantastic and the source of most of what I know about JavaScript. :-)

Comment: Have you read / would you recommend /The Good Parts/? A friend of mine has it so I could borrow it if I wanted.

Comment: Also, any specific lectures you'd recommend as a gateway?

Comment: I own "The Good Parts", it's a fantastic book and I would recommend it. It's short and easy to read and hits on pretty much everything Crockford discusses in his lectures. As for which ones to watch, I think the first 6 are the most useful (7 and 8 are kind of supplementary). The first lecture can be skipped if you want because it doesn't discuss JavaScript at all, but it's really interesting and entertaining and provides some useful background on the development of programming languages, so I would recommend it if you have the time.

Comment: +1 Great answer. All of this is covered (and more) at the link I posted earlier: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ (Incidentally, I think we used to work at the same company. It's a small interweb.)

Comment: @lwburk Yeah, I've moved on to a company that actually gives a crap about their clients and associates. (offtopic)

Answer (score 4):

For the function to call itself.

```
var x = function y(val){
            if (val){
                console.log(val);
                y(val-1);
            }
        }; 
x(5);
> 3  
> 2  
> 1 
y(3); 
> ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

Comment: Okay, so then they don't conflict with anything else then, really.  IE, you could have: 

`var x = function z(v) { if (v) {console.log(v); z(v-1);} };
var y = function z(v) { if (v) {console.log(v); z(v-1);} };`

Comment: note the two functions that are both internally labelled `z`.

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to a *named function expression*. The spec requires that the name of such functions only be available within the scope of the new function. [Spec quote](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13):

> The Identifier in a FunctionExpression can be referenced from inside
>   the FunctionExpression's FunctionBody to allow the function to call
>   itself recursively. However, unlike in a FunctionDeclaration, the
>   Identifier in a FunctionExpression cannot be referenced from and does
>   not affect the scope enclosing the FunctionExpression.

On the other hand, the *result* of that expression is a reference to the new function, which can be saved and referenced anywhere.

Lots of details here:

- http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#named-expr

I'd read the whole thing.

As for benefits, another is that it makes them easier to identify in a debugger.

Comment: Very interesting, and complicated.